# android not able to locte IDs

Tags: android

I had a fully working app, but today when I opened it in eclipse it could not find any of my resource ids(Buttons, EditTexts, TextViews, and layouts). I have no clue why this is happening. It is as though I forgot to give my buttons an id in XML, but when I go to the files they are still there.
Has anyone else had this problem/know how to solve it ?

**EDIT:**
I should also add that if I look in R.java , all my ids are there

Comment: have you tried to clean your project?

Comment: In your Package Explorer window, verify that this project does not have a error icon in your res folders. A simple error in an XML file, will prevent the R file from building preventing you from finding any resources. After this, then Clean your project removing any android.R import files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i faced the same issue. i checked the **AndroidManifest** file same code repeated two times. so i

> removed the repeating tag from the xml

after that i clean and compiled, then it was working fine.

> also check your adt version version. make sure that is upto date.

Comment: Thanks! I feel really relieved now, I was worried I would have to recode all of it!